# message.guild.roles.find is not a function

Tags: discord.js

**EDITED FOR SELF ANSWER**

`message.guild.roles.find is not a function` Is a result of using a DJS v11 method on DJS v12, in other words `message.guild.roles.find` is outdated and should be replaced with

`message.guild.roles.cache.find`

DJS v11 is now discontinued. Follow this guide to update your code for v12 [Here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Comment: Ive edited my question to help those who have the issue today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you now have to use `message.guild.roles.cache.find`, since v12 uses Managers.
You can read the [documentation](https://discord.js.org) to find the other changes by yourself.

Comment: The link for changes is https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html